# Releasing commerical PHP code. Do you obfuscate or compile it? Or just deliver as-is?

Tags: php, release, obfuscation

Possible reasons:

1) so the user can't figure out the code and "issue himself more licenses" or other stuff that is commercially sensitive to you

2) so the user can't "just make a tiny change" and break what he doesn't understand, then tell you he didn't change anything and expect you to fix it (sure, you can make him pay, but it's easier to avoid the hassle in the first place)

3) so the customer can't take some of your software and use it do develop new products

4) you are embarrassed to let your uncommented spaghetti code be seen ;-)

5) any more?

What do you generally do? And how do you do it?

Comment: Do you retain the ownership of the code ?

Comment: There is an **abundance** of PHP applications. Mostly open source. If you've found a customer who hasn't researched free options, it seems highly unlikely that this very customer will try to customize your code and develop a software business around.

Comment: +1 to both "Do you retain the ownership of the code?" a good question. But, unless you explicitly sell it as a development platform, I don't see a problem (they purchased the code - but if you only ever deliver obfuscated code, then that is what they purchase - unless teh contract explicitly states un-obfuscated). But you can be 100% sure that if you deliver cleartext code and they modify it then you will get the support headaches and they generally won't be prepared to pay

Comment: Let's look at it another way. It should be analogous to delivering C source code or an .EXE - I guess it's down to what the contract says. But generally they can expect to pay more for source code - and can't expect to get source to everything, e.g., the licensing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one has addressed that delivering the licensing source allows customers to switch it off and have unlimited licences. That is my main concern

Answer (score 2):

If hosting the php code on your servers is not an option, the best thing is to simply deliver the source code with a restrictive license and accept the risks you outlined above. If the user "issues more licenses" and it violates your terms, you can pursue legal actions.

Answer (score 2):

On the receiving end, I have purchased PHP software that was ofsucated/encoded with ionCube PHP Encoder (http://www.ioncube.com/).  It required adding an additional server component and including effectively closed-source code no our servers, neither of which our IT team was happy about.  But it prevented us from fiddling with the source as you are attempting.

Answer (score 2):

I deliver it as is. End-users expect to be able to edit the code whether it's free or commercial. Most of them aren't pirates, so getting in their way will just hurt your business (less happy customers = less positive mentions and referrals). The pirates will steal your software whether you obfuscate/encode it or not, anyway.

Comment: +1 I agree that you can't beat pirates. But customers who have the source code tend to break it, claim to have changed nothing, and expect you to fix it - for free. Plus I don't want to give out the source to my licensing system.

Comment: I have sold non-obfuscated PHP code to thousands of generally non-technical users. Having a customer break the code then ask for me to fix it virtually never happened. Not giving out the source to the licensing system wasn't a problem since I did not have one in the first place. There were licenses, but they were enforced by law, not by software. DRM doesn't help your customers, and it doesn't help you either.

Comment: "End users expect to be able to edit the code"?  You haven't met a Microsoft Product.

Comment: When people buy a Microsoft product off the shelf, they don't expect to edit the code. When they buy a PHP script for their website, where they're used to editing all the code for their site, and the tens of thousands of free PHP scripts they can download, they do expect to be able to edit the code.

Comment: +1 to both. Maybe I should have asked "what would MS do if they sold PHP based products?"  I have to say that 1) my users are very un-tech-savvy 2) they can hack the CSS if they want too 3) the code & database have an extremely complex and delicate relationship; the slightest change is likely to break everything 4) I offer lots of customization options 5) if someone needs something different, then I am betetr suited to change it than they

Answer (score 2):

If a client breaks my code and try to pin it on me I offer to restore the code to the last known working configuration. This usually ends the conversation because they know it was a modification they made.

Seems like an unnecessary precaution to me. Even if you obfuscate it it can still be redistributed. As a developer, piracy is a known risk and the best way to avoid it is to release software that is open source. :)

I would seriously think twice about doing business with a developer in the future if I purchased a script that was obfuscated (making it difficult for me to make changes). I mean.. what PHP script needs ZERO modification to get it to do exactly what you want it to?

Comment: "offer to restore the code to the last known working configuration" +1  Simple, but efficient. A wonderful idea.

Comment: "what PHP script needs ZERO modification to get it to do exactly what you want it to?" a will written one? I make everything as customizable as possible thous CSS, external data files and configuration pages in the PHP code itself. I suppose much depends if you are selling to multiple clients. For a single client, clearly defined requirements should mean that no configuration is necessary. And even where it is, there is the question of who is best suited to do it? The original developers or a 3rd party.

Comment: I meant as a developer myself, I have rarely downloaded a script that I didn't have to modify at least slightly to get it to do exactly what I want. Even a lot of popular API's have some custom code inserted into them by me. I would hate it if I purchased somebody's code that was unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning point #2:

You can always generate a hash of your deliverables. Very simple method: generate an md5 hash using the source files as input. If you suspect tampering when receiving a support call, simply hash the deployed files to figure out if your client has tampered with the code and tries to get you to fix their mess.

This is non-intrusive (you just hash before you deliver, and keep the hashes in your files) and a quite safe way to check the contents of your files.

Comment: +1 thanks. I had thought of that, but I still worry that the user might try to hack the licensing (which is in the database, rather than the PHP code, but reading the code would show the user where).